# How to extract conversion results based on different attribution models from the Google Adwords API

Tags: google-ads-api, awql

I need to extract data from the adwords API to allow me to see the impact of different attribution models on conversion. I'm visualising my adwords data in the Klipfolio tool. My adwords account is set up to use the position based model but I'd also like to show last click conversions. This is essentially the data which is available in the adwords manager interface. I'm making my API calls via the supermetrics tool but can also create them directly in Klipfolio.

I'm not entirely familiar with the adwords query language but it does look like that there is a field for attribution type.

I've got as far as extracting data via this, using the Klipfolio interface:

```
SELECT 
Date,Conversions,ConversionTypeName
FROM CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT

DURING {date.add(-7).format('yyyyMMdd')},{date.today.format('yyyyMMdd')}
```

Exactly what I'm looking for is WHERE function where I can specify a different type of attribution model from the current.

I cannot obtain this data from our Google Analytics data as our conversion data from GA is, unfortunately, duplicated. We're using the adword's conversion tags de-duplication functions to get around this issue.

I'd be very grateful if anyone could share an example of how an API request could look with the attribution model field present or, indeed, give some feedback on whether this is even possible.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can find more information about the CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT report [here](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/campaign-performance-report)

You can find there the WHERE and SELECT fields like this:

```
 SELECT CampaignName, Clicks, Impressions, Cost 
  FROM   CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT 
  WHERE  Impressions < 10 
  DURING LAST_30_DAYS'
```

Usually the reason for the duplications it's the selection of SELECT parameters, but I cannot say this for sure without more information.